# How do you use dynamic ng-show values inside a directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am learning angular, and I am trying to reduce some code that it takes to do some common things, like display error messages, by using angular directives.

One directive I would like to create is like this:

```
<error-message name="paymentPlanForm.position" error="required">
    This field is required.
</error-message>
```

This would generate the following:

```
<p ng-show="paymentPlanForm.position.$dirty && paymentPlanForm.position.$error.required">
    <span class="fontawesome-remove"></span> This field is required.
</p>
```

I started to write a directive to accomplish this as follows:

```
app.directive("errorMessage", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'views/partials/errorMessage.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.name = attributes.name;
            scope.error = attributes.error;
        }
    }
});
```

The template is as follows:

```
<p ng-show="{{name}}.$dirty && {{name}}.$error.{{error}}">
    <span class="fontawesome-remove"></span>
    <span ng-transclude></span>
</p>
```

I thought this would work, but Angular seems to crash when trying to parse `ng-show` inside the template:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [.$dirty && .$error.] starting at [.$dirty && .$error.].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/$parse/syntax?p0=.&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=.%24dirty%20%26%26%20.%24error.&p4=.%24dirty%20%26%26%20.%24error.
minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/keiko/vendor/js/angular.js:78
```

When I inspect the element in Firebug, the dynamic values have been passed in successfully, but I guess there's a problem with the scope, or something else.

How can I get angular to do what I want?

Comment: Are you able to setup a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your link function runs after the template has been compiled by Angular. So `name` and `error` haven't been set during compilation when `ngShow` checks its attributes (thus the error where it see's a "." without anything in front of it).

`ngShow` only looks at its attributes at compile, it then watches whatever expression was passed in at that point.  So it never sees that the link function changes its attribute.

The html has been updated by the time you look at it, which makes it all the more confusing.

My recommendation is to use an isolate scope and pass those two attributes in that way.  That'll address the timing, plus it's not a bad idea to use isolate scopes for this kind of directive anyway:

```
scope:{
        name: '@',
        error: '@'
     },
```

The one trade off is now the form data will be on the directive's parent's scope, so we'll need to add a `$parent` reference within your template:

```
template: '<div><p ng-show="$parent.{{name}}.$dirty">Dirty</p><p ng-show="$parent.{{name}}.$error.{{error}}"><span ng-transclude></span></p></div>',
```

Note I tweaked your template to separate the dirty and the required tests just to make it easier to see it working.

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZL6h/2/)