# Angular: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create tooltips in an `ng-repeat` with [angular-tooltips](https://github.com/720kb/angular-tooltips). The content of the tooltips has to be dynamically. What I already have is something like this:

**View:**

```
<div ng-repeat="region in regions">
    <a tooltips tooltip-html="{{ myCtrl.generateTooltip(region) }}">HOVER</a>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function generateTooltip(region) {
    // generate some html here
    var content = "<b>HELLO WORLD!</b>";
    return $sce.trustAsHtml( content );
}
```

The tooltip is shown and working, but I get the following error in console (which I don't want to see :-))

```
 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary
 expression at column 1 of the expression [<b>HELLO WORLD!</b>]
 starting at [<b>HELLO WORLD!</b>].
```

1. What is wrong with my code?
2. Is it possible to use a view as the tooltip instead of generating the HTML in the controller? There is an attribute `tooltip-view`, but I don't know how to pass my `region` variable to it.

Comment: you don't need the `{{ }}` here; the return value of the function isn't an expression that angular needs to evaluate.

Comment: If I remove the `{{ }}`, the content of the tooltip is "myCtrl.generateTooltip(region)" ;-)

Comment: Try the following (exactly): "'<b>HELLO WORLD!</b>'" (single quotes inside the double quotes).

Comment: @DavidM.Karr: `Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context.`, although I am using `$sce.trustAsHtml()`...

Comment: Seems like you didn't include `angular-sanitize.js`.

Comment: @zeroflagL: That did it! Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Someone else had a similar error resulting from a function running after the template was compiled by angular. Maybe [this will set you in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273912/how-do-you-use-dynamic-ng-show-values-inside-a-directive-template).

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `angular-sanitize.js` which sanitize inputs by parsing the HTML into tokens. All safe tokens (from a whitelist) are then serialized back to properly escaped HTML string. This means that no unsafe input can make it into the returned string.